# Spring Integration JDBC inbound poller Java Based Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I want to configure an Inbound pooler with Spring Integration JDBC. So far I have found xml configuration but I want to implement in java configuration.

I want to continuously check for changes in db table and I think this is achievable with Spring Integration JDBC.

My Db is in different Docker Container and my Application (Spring Boot) is in different Docker Container. I Can not use Hibernate Interceptor here because some other application will edit table.

Comment: For those who face this issue, I have implemented the sample spring application 
[link](https://github.com/Umair-Ansari/SpringIntegrationJDBCInboundPooler)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what resources have you investigated, but we have on first pages of our official [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/overview.html#_finding_class_names_for_java_and_dsl_configuration) this sample:

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "fooChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay="5000"))
public MessageSource<?> storedProc(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(dataSource, "SELECT * FROM foo where status = 0");
}
```

The chapter is called `Finding Class Names for Java and DSL Configuration`. So, should be as a good migration guide from XML configuration.

Comment: Hey! I have already found solution of my problem. Your answer is right. I have converted xml configuration to java configuration.